# touchesBegan caught by AppDelegate instead of subclass of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, appdelegate, touchesbegan

I was going through Chapter 5 of the iOS Programming by The Big Nerd Ranch Guide (4th edition, wanted Objective C), I followed the instructions on subclassing the `UIView` class and added the subview in `AppDelegate`, the thing is that the **subview is not catching the `touchesBegan` event,** **but the `AppDelegate` is catching the signal.**

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate`:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window setRootViewController:[UIViewController alloc]];

CGRect firstFrame = self.window.bounds;

HypnosisView *firstView = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:firstFrame];
[self.window addSubview:firstView];
[firstView becomeFirstResponder];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

The two initialization methods for `HypnosisView`, subclass of `UIView` are defined as follows:

```
#import "HypnosisView.h"

@interface HypnosisView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *circleColor;

@end

@implementation HypnosisView

// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    CGRect frame = self.frame;

    // Figure out the center of the bounds rectangle
    CGPoint center;
     center.x = frame.origin.x + frame.size.width / 2.0;
    center.y = frame.origin.y + frame.size.height / 2.0;

    // The largest circle will circumscribe the view
    float maxRadius = hypot(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2.0;

     UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];

    for (float currentRadius = maxRadius; currentRadius > 0; currentRadius -= 20) {
        [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x + currentRadius, center.y)];

        [path addArcWithCenter:center
                    radius:currentRadius
                startAngle:0.0
                  endAngle:M_PI * 2
                 clockwise:YES];
    }

    // Configure line with to 10 points
    path.lineWidth = 10;

    // Configure the drawing color to light gray
    [self.circleColor setStroke];

    // Draw the line!
    [path stroke];
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // All HypnosisViews start with a clear background color
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.circleColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"%@ was touched", self);
}
```

Comment: If the code comes from the book, you shouldn't post it here.  It's their intellectual property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Appdelegate.m`, you should `makeKeyAndVisible` your `window` firstly, `makeKeyAndVisible` will set the `window` to `keyWindow`, and will bring the `window` to the front of all of your `windows`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:[UIViewController alloc]];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    CGRect firstFrame = self.window.bounds;

    HypnosisView *firstView = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:firstFrame];
    [self.window addSubview:firstView];
    [firstView becomeFirstResponder];



    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! But why does the order of setting background color make a difference?

Comment: @TPWang not  `setting background color`, but `[self.window addSubview:firstView];`, see my edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

UIView objects don't normally react to touch events. Did you set the userInteractionEnabled flag to true for your views?

And where is the touchesBegan method that's not getting called?

Comment: I've added the touchesBegan function that is supposed to be called but not, the HypnosisView is not getting touches event but the same function is called in the AppDelegate, this is what I don't understand.

And I did set userInteractionEnabled to YES, btw none of the existing answers helped, I'm a starter, but what looks fishy to me is how the window is started in AppDelegate, could you take a look at that?

Comment: You did not show either of those things (your touchesBegan method, or the code that sets userInteractionEnabled to true.)

Comment: Your code is also setting the root view controller of the app window to a view controller that you allocate but never initialize, which is wrong. Why are you mucking around with trying to install views directly in the app window, and messing with the way the root view controller gets set up?

Comment: Please scroll down the second part of code. Sorry to put it down there.

Comment: I was following the Big Nerd Rand book as I have no idea how things are done properly, but I was surprised that the default ViewController was not involved in it

Comment: There is rarely a reason to do that. If you're just starting out, toss any book that uses Objective-C and pick up a Swift-3 based book. It's good to be able to understand Objective-C, but as a new learner you should be focusing on Swift.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130823/discussion-between-tpwang-and-duncan-c).